# Is each issue of a magazine site a static page

Tags: archives, date, customization

I want to create a monthly magazine style website.

I can see the url for a month is something like this:
www.magazine.com/mywebpage/2013/08

Suppose I want to create a custom page for each month, do I create static pages for each month?

If I do that, how do I display the static page when the user clicks on the date archive?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the buildin archives, your best way of achieving this is to create a Page Template containing nearly the same code as the `archive.php`.

Also, add some `post_meta` to your static pages, containing the Year and Month of the posts you want to show.

In your page template, set up a custom query containing the restriction for the date, with the `$args`:

```
$args = array (
    'year' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_year_meta', true ),
    'monthnum' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_month_meta', true )
    'offset' => $offset,
    //...
);
```

Make the query as usual, and use the code from your `archive.php` to loop through the posts.

Also make sure that, if you want your posts paginated, you calculate the custom offset right, and this should be it :)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will work on this and get back.  I did have a clarification.  On a magazine site, do they use a template?  Does it make sense to create static pages to customize each issue, e.g, january.html, feburary.html, etc.